# How to manage a project on GitHub that has an external git dependency not stored on GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, mupdf

I'm working on a project that I'd like to store on GitHub.

This project uses mupdf, which is hosted on it's own git server, e.g. git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git

I want to be able to get the latest changes from mupdf, but also keep changes that I make to mupdf, while keeping my whole project on GitHub.

My first thought was to add mupdf as a submodule and then push my project to GitHub-- but what happens to changes I make to mupdf (e.g. inside the submodle)? Where do I store those? My understanding was that if I make a change inside the submodule, the commit there will only be stored locally. I read this page http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules , but was left unsure whether this will work.

What's the best way to set up my repo, such that:

1) My entire project is on GitHub
2) I can get new changes from mupdf into my project
3) I can preserve my changes to mupdf and merge them with new changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your submodule's repo to github as well. If you would like that to be the default where the repo resides, make the adjustment in the `.gitmodules` file in the root of your working folder. Then issue

```
git submodule init
```

to propagate the new url to the `.git/config` in the submodule.

Comment: And how do you pull in new upstream changes into the submodule / merge existing changes?

Comment: it's done at the top level. The tree contains the sha1 of what the submodule's current commit it is. This can continue recursively with `git submodule update --recursive`.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing: 1) git submodule add git:// .. 2) git submodule init 3) cd submodule 4) git checkout -b MyBranch 5) git remote add Github git://... 6) git push Github MyBranch .

Answer (score 1):

You would either have to push changes to the other git repository (wherever it may be stored) or create a fork of that repository on GitHub and make your changes there.